# MySql Error 1241 on Insert Statement

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

This is my code, and it is giving me: **"Error Code 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)"**. I have been staring at it for a few hours now and I **cannot figure out what is causing it.** I can provide the create table statement too if that would help. Additionally I am using MySQL Workbench 56.

Sorry for the poorly formatted code, this is my first post, so if I have broken any rules please let me know. I am happy to resubmit it.

Old Code:

```
    INSERT INTO sales (sales_id, sales, salesman, customer, date, region) 

VALUES
(
(null,null,null,...),
(...),

);
```

**Corrected Code:**

```
INSERT INTO sales (sales_id, sales, salesman, customer, date, region) 
VALUES
  (null, 2456.00, 'Barb', 'D-Square', '2014/06/10', 'N Reg'),
  (null, 3894.00, 'Barb', 'Lowes', '2014/05/08', 'N Reg'),
  ...(last row);
```

Two things I think will help clarify how I fixed this. First, I rearranged everything as recommended in the chosen answer, but also realized that my VALUES statement had too many parentheses.

It *was*: VALUES ((first row),(second row),... );

But the correct way was actually: **VALUES (first row), (second row)... (last row);**

I didn't realize that the input "bookends" of the statement were **VALUES** ... and... **;**

Additionally my **dates** were formatted incorrectly, should have been YYYY/MM/DD instead of MM/DD/YYYY

Thanks for all the help! I am so amazed at how active and fast this community is. You guys are life savers.

Comment: Sooo, you are trying to insert 28 columns into 6 columns?

Comment: @Lamak: No. He is trying to insert 28 rows of 1 column values into 1 column at 1 call. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your `insert` is that you have flipped your data: insert expects values organized row-by-row, like in a table. You provided the data organized column-by-column.

Once you "flip" the data to put it in the right order, the insertion will work:

```
INSERT INTO sales (sales_id, sales, salesman, customer, date, region)
VALUES
    (null, 2456.00, 'Barb', '06/10/2014', 'D-Square', 'N Reg')
,   (null, 3894.00, 'Barb', '05/08/2014', 'Lowes', 'N Reg')
,   ... -- And so on for the remaining 26 rows
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I did what you said, along with some other little things I was overlooking and it worked. If you or anyone is interested I updated my question to include the fix so that anyone else having the issue can be on the watch for similar mistakes. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to do a multiinsert but you got the syntax wrong
It looks like:

```
INSERT INTO sales (sales_id, sales, salesman, customer, date, region) 

VALUES(null, 2456.00, 'Barb', '06/10/2014', 'D-Square', 'N Reg'),
(null, 3894.00, 'Barb', '05/08/2014', 'Lowes', 'N Reg'),
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I can't pick two correct answers, but your answer also helped me get the code right. I added all the changes I made as an edit to my first post if you would like to see it. Thanks again for your help!